# Bridge table with no primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, database-first, ef-database-first

I have a bridge table in my database design and it does not have a primary key. When I try to use the database first approach for ASP.NET MVC 3 to create my model, it creates a model with a warning saying **"The table/view 'CRM_Test_1.dbo.SalesOrderProduct' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it."**

Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to make this warning go away??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a primary key (int, autonumber) if you want to suppress the error message.  Some would say that you NEED a primary key.  Or you could make a compound key of the bridged ids, if that makes sense in your data model.

Comment: Adding a auto number primary key has no real advantage as discussed in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190272/sql-many-to-many-table-primary-key).

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework uses the Primary key to create the unique Entity Key for each record. If there is no primary key on the table it does display a warning that you see.

Its not wrong per say. But you could add an identity column to the table as the primary key. This will make the warning go away.