# MySQL design one-to-many?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a database that deals with students. So I have table Students and Classes. Now every Student can go to as many classes as s/he wants; how would I model this in a MySQL database schema?

Students table:

```
student_id
student_name
student_age
...
```

Classes table:

```
class_id
class_name
class_profesor
...
```

Basically I don't know how to design a table where one student could register him- or herself for as many classes as s/he wants?

Should I make another table for this?
Is this a one-to-many relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a many-to-many or mapping table, e.g.:

```
class_student
-------------
class_id
student_id
```

Primary key for this table should be:  `(class_id, student_id)`.
Create an index on:
    `(class_id, student_id)`, and
    `(student_id, class_id)`.
Take a gander at [this other SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190272/sql-many-to-many-table-primary-key) for more detail.

---

Once you've got that set up, you can query for enrollees to a given class with:

```
SELECT c.class_name, s.student_name, ...
FROM   class_student cs
       LEFT JOIN class c   ON c.class_id = cs.class_id
       LEFT JOIN student s ON s.student_id = cs.student_id
WHERE  cs.class_id = '<some_class_id_here>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain one more table 'Goes_to' which will store only student_id and class_id.This will normalize your data as well as you can write different types of queries based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Bernie, this is a Many to Many relationship. In addition to what Bernie explained, you can add extra fields to 'class_student' table, like for example student's average grade on that class, or how many times he didn't went to that class.