# Is there any way to embed a class Element into a class Element in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, class, entity-framework-core

This is my code:

```
namespace MyProject.Models.Database
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Picture { get; set; }
        public int Worktime { get; set; }
        public int? Cooktime { get; set; }
        public int Difficulty { get; set; }
        public int Portions { get; set; }
        public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    }
    public class Ingredient
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public Guid IngredientId { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public string QtyUnit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want the class "Recipe" to include many elements of type "Ingredient". Ive read stuff about One-to-One and Many-To-Many but i just dont get it...

any Ideas?
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One recipe can consist of many ingredients, one ingredient can also be in many recipes. This is a many-to-many relationship.

What you need to do is create a new class that contains `Id`, `RecipeId`, `IngredientId`.Name that class something like RecipeIngredient. When you are creating a `DbSet<RecipeIngredient>` in your db context, name your table `RecipesIngredients`.

What should be the data types of the properties in `RecipeIngredient`?

The `Id` property will be the primary key, you can decide the data type.

`RecipeId` will be a foreign key for the Recipe, so it needs the same data type as the primary key of the Recipe (in your case `Guid`).

`IngredientId` will be the foreign key for the `Ingredient`, so the data type will again be `Guid` in your case.

Note that instead of putting `Id` in your RecipeIngredient, you can create a composite key instead.

When should you do that? -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190272/sql-many-to-many-table-primary-key)

I suggest you learn about the different relationships and how to apply them using C# and Entity Framework Core -> [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Good luck on your learning journey! When you don't feel you understand a topic, don't worry and don't get discouraged, you just need more experience. Keep up the good work :)